# Creating a 'shortcut' for \mathcal{...}

Tags: math-mode, equations, amsmath

I am writing a document where I use the `\mathcal{...}` a lot. Is it possible to create a shortcut, such as `\mc{}`?

Comment: Yes, `\newcommand\mc{\mathcal}` but in general my advice would be to use an editor that can do it. For example, I can write `&` and push tab and my editor will add `\mathcal{ }` for me... it's more general, and you'll have a document easier to read for everybody.
BTW: Welcome to the site!

Comment: Perfect, that's what I needed. Thank you. :)

Comment: That is not good idea. For example, at writing tables is quit common to define new command  `\mc` as shortcut for `\multicolumn{...}{...}{....}`.  So it can become easy to forgot meaning of `˙\mc` ... Typing for letters more is not such deal and at this you can use support of editor to finish word instead of you ...

Comment: @Zarko added in my answer. I use  `\multicolumn` there; I can teach `vim` to expand `\mc` to it in no time...

Comment: @Zarko, \mc was just an example to express that I wanted a shortcut for \mathcal. But thanks for the comment. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer to the question is [quite straightforward](https://www.learnlatex.org/en/lesson-06):

```
\newcommand\mc{\mathcal}
```

will do the trick. But probably it's not such a good idea; let's see why.

Start here and after a while, you will have a collection of shorthand macros (`\mc`, `\mb`,  `\tp`, `\ll`) on the top of your document. You'll copy and paste that around and after a while:

- you will have to jump back and forth because you have no idea about what `\tp` was supposed to do;
- sooner or later you will hit a macro from one package or another and get an error or very strange things, or even you'll find that you have used `\mc` for a different thing in a different file, and merging them will be a little nightmare;
- even if you remember it, your colleague which is proofreading the text will mildly hate you;
- most editors of journals (that normally translate the source to things that are not exactly LaTeX) will less mildly hate you.

It is much more sensible to use an editor that lets you do substitutions on the fly; most of them do. That way you will have normally even fewer keystrokes to type, but the source will be clearer and everybody will be able to read it fluently. For example, I can type `*`<kbd>TAB</kbd> and my editor will input `\textbf{}` for me with the cursor between the braces (and I will jump out with another <kbd>TAB</kbd>).

If you are serious with LaTeX, the time spent in learning to use an advanced editor is time very well spent that will repay off *a lot*.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am not going to use \mc, it was just meant as an easy example. I will use \eff (short for 'effective' - no point in explaining the meaning of this, but it is very clear from the article I am writing).

Comment: Yes --- using the macro for the *semantic* is an appropriate thing to do. So if you change your mind on how "effective" should be displayed, you can change only in one place!

Comment: I am writing the article with a professor who preferred to write in Overleaf. Is it possible to do something similar to what you suggested, and for example use *[TAB] for \mathcal{}?

Comment: Hmmm, no idea, you should ask the overleaf people...

Answer (score 9):

If you decide for a shortcut, it should *not* be `\mc`, which carries even less semantics than `\mathcal` and so it's difficult to remember.

Choose a shortcut that does carry a meaning, or no shortcut at all. Just as an example, suppose you decide to use calligraphic letters for denoting categories. Then it makes sense to do

```
\newcommand{\cat}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
```

(or, if you're a purist, `\newcommand{\cat}{\mathcal}`). If those letters denote Hilbert spaces, then you can define

```
\newcommand{\hs}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
\newcommand{\hh}{\hs{H}} % the generic Hilbert space
```

Choose a mnemonic name that suits you. Maybe you have an occasional `\mathcal{Q}` somewhere that *doesn't* denote a Hilbert space (math notation is not always consistent because of lack of alphabets); in that case you *will* use `\mathcal{Q}`.

This makes even more sense if it happens that you change your mind about how to denote Hilbert spaces; say that your coauthor doesn't like calligraphic letters for them, but Fraktur. Then all you need is to change the definition of `\hs` to be

```
\newcommand{\hs}{\mathfrak{#1}}
```

and all your Hilbert spaces will become Fraktur with no further hassle. But the occasional `\mathcal{Q}` will remain calligraphic!

To the contrary, if you happen to have many `\multicolumn` commands in your document it can make sense to define `\mc` as a shorthand. Is it difficult to remember? Not really: it will only appear in the context of `tabular` or `array` (or maybe `longtable`) and staring at the command for one second will remind you what it means.